# How do you recompile an .el source file and make it active in my current session

Tags: byte-compilation, eval, load

I have been writing some elisp code, current i have to open the file edit quit and reload emacs seems there must be a better way ?

I know i can recompile the current file but that does not seem to make my changes active with in emacs until i restart is there something else i should be doing to make emacs use the new compiled file ?

Comment: There are several ways to (re-)evaluate Elisp, regardless of whether it lives in a buffer or file or is byte-compiled. For example, you can [repeatedly read an Elisp file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Repeated-Loading.html) with `M-x load-file RET <file> RET`. See also [how to `eval` Elisp buffers](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Eval.html) and the [`auto-compile`](https://github.com/emacscollective/auto-compile) package.

Comment: Excellent, make that an answer if you like and i will accept. basically eval-buffer is what i needed instead of compile. Just tried and my changes now apply when i run that.

Comment: Use `load-library`. If the file is in your `load-path` then that will automatically prefer to pick up the byte-compiled file (`*.elc`) rather than the source file (`*.el`).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> How do you recompile an .el source file [...]

1. In Elisp [file-visiting](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Visiting.html) buffers, you can run the command <kbd>M-x</kbd>`emacs-lisp-byte-compile`<kbd>RET</kbd> to byte-compile the corresponding file.
2. In [Dired](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Dired.html) buffers, you can type <kbd>B</kbd> (`dired-do-byte-compile`) to byte-compile all specified Elisp files.
3. In all buffers, you can run the command <kbd>M-x</kbd>`byte-compile-file`<kbd>RET</kbd> to byte-compile an arbitrary file prompted with completion.

> [...] and make it active in my current session

1. Similar to the aforementioned `emacs-lisp-byte-compile`, the command <kbd>M-x</kbd>`emacs-lisp-byte-compile-and-load`<kbd>RET</kbd> will byte-compile the current file, if necessary, before loading it.
2. Typing <kbd>L</kbd> (`dired-do-load`) in a Dired buffer will load the corresponding file.
3. Passing a prefix argument to <kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>M-x</kbd>`byte-compile-file`<kbd>RET</kbd> will prompt for and byte-compile an arbitrary file as usual before additionally loading it.

> I have been writing some elisp code, current i have to open the file edit quit and reload emacs seems there must be a better way ?

There are various alternative approaches you could take, depending on your preferred workflow:

1. Emacs provides several commands for evaluating Elisp at varying degrees of granularity and from various sources, such as in-buffer expressions or expressions read from the minibuffer. See [`(emacs) Lisp Eval`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Lisp-Eval.html).
2. You can load Elisp files/libraries via the commands `load-file` and `load-library`, as Drew mentions in [a comment](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/35923/how-do-you-recompile-an-el-source-file-and-make-it-active-in-my-current-session#comment56596_35923). See [`(emacs) Lisp Libraries`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Lisp-Libraries.html).

See also the package [`auto-compile`](https://github.com/emacscollective/auto-compile) for automatically compiling Elisp files on save/load.

**Edit**

As Tobias correctly warns in [a comment](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/35923/how-do-you-recompile-an-el-source-file-and-make-it-active-in-my-current-session/38223?noredirect=1#comment60224_38223), there are many caveats associated with reevaluation of Elisp, which is not always straight-forward. Two common pitfalls are:

1. Contrary to `defun`, `defvar` and `defcustom` forms do not reset their `INITVALUE` and `STANDARD` arguments, respectively, when reloaded (i.e. when they have already been defined and set). Only a call to <kbd>C-M-x</kbd> (`eval-defun`) in their vicinity will reset their value. [Since Emacs 28, <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-e</kbd> (`eval-last-sexp`) handles `defvar`, `defcustom`, and `defface` forms in a similar way to `eval-defun`.]
2. Reloading/redefining a macro will cause its new definition to be used henceforth, but all previously expanded call sites will have been expanded according to the old definition. Each call site has to be reevaluated and/or byte-compiled for the expansion to occur using the new macro definition.

Comment: Re-evaluating changed lisp sources can be nifty. There is the problem with `defcustom` and with `defvar`. If you change the value in such forms this takes no direct effect if you reload. Furthermore, if you change a macro (or a `defsubst`) you need to reload all sources where this macro is used. Otherwise the old macro definition keeps in effect. Perhaps a warning about such effects is in place (even if it does not directly address the question).

Comment: @Tobias Thanks, I've updated the answer.