# reload emacs package in current session after .el source recompilation

Tags: package, load

I have an emacs package installed from `elpa` in my `${HOME}/.emacs.d/elpa/` directory, and I am trying to fiddle with its `.el` source file. I would like to

- recompile after modification
- have those changes take effect in the current `emacs` session, without quitting.

This seems similar to [another question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/35923/how-do-you-recompile-an-el-source-file-and-make-it-active-in-my-current-session), but nothing mentioned there that I've tried works:

- `M-x emacs-lisp-byte-compile-and-load`
- reloading my `.emacs` after byte-recompilation
- `load-library RET <library name>`
- `eval-buffer`
- `load-file RET <path to corresponding .elc file>`
- remove `.elc` file completely and  `load-file RET <path to .el file>`

*None* of these work as intended: the package does not reload, as I can confirm quite easily by breaking / unbreaking some of its functions.

Comment: For me (in spacemacs) `emacs-lisp-byte-compile-and-load` works on a package file in `.emacs.d/elpa/27.2/develop/<package>...`.