# Symbol’s function definition is void: make-closure

Tags: error, backtrace

I’m trying to split a number stated in scientific notation (`6.371e6`) and write it as float (`6371000`) (I’m doing this to learn.)

This is the code I have so far

```
A = (car (mapcar #'string-to-number (split-string "6.371e6" "e")))
6.371


B = (nth 1 (mapcar #'string-to-number (split-string "6.371e6" "e")))
6
```

When I try

```
(* A B)
```

I get this error:

```
symbol’s function definition is void: make-closure
```

Why do I get this error?

I found [this link](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/qbnrao/symbols_function_definition_is_void_makeclosure/), but I did not understand what I need to do. Do I need to upgrade my emacs? I have version 27.2

Also, why don't I get the `*Backtrace*` buffer? Instead, the errors show up in the mini buffer.

Comment: Say `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` to get the backtrace. Use `setq` for the assignments (otherwise `A` and `B` are undefined. And clean up (some of) your `*.elc` files: if the link is correct, they have been compiled with a newer version of  emacs. For a file `foo.elc`, you can find what version of the compiler compiled it by running `file foo.elc` at a shell prompt.

Comment: I am having trouble finding any `.elc` files. In fact, I'm having problems with `find-name-dired`. I'll ask another question.

Comment: Ok, I restarted emacs and found the `.elc` files. Do I need to delete them?

Comment: This page recommends deleting all `.elc` files https://blog.codeselfstudy.com/blog/how-to-remove-all-elc-files-emacs/

Comment: You will need to recompile them, which is a big job. That's why I suggested you check which ones are compiled with which compiler. There are two broad classes: ones in `/usr/share/emacs/27.2` which *should* be fine and should probably be left alone. And ones under `~/.emacs.d/elpa` or some similar place for packages you have downloaded and which are probably suspect.

Comment: Yes, it looks like v.23: `.emacs.d/elpa/epresent-20160411.201/epresent.elc: Emacs/XEmacs v23 byte-compiled Lisp data`

Comment: I guess this is how recompile: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/35923/how-do-you-recompile-an-el-source-file-and-make-it-active-in-my-current-session  But afer restarting now I didn't have any problems.

Comment: `v23` was the compiler version until Emacs 28 when it became `v28`, so `v23` files do not need to be recompiled for Emacs 27.2. At least, AFAIK...

Answer (score 1):

You need to recompile the `.elc` files.

```el
(byte-recompile-directory package-user-dir nil 'force)
```

I had to restart and compile twice.

[found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24725778/how-to-rebuild-elpa-packages-after-upgrade-of-emacs)