# Modify how task list percentages (% cookie) display in an org-mode document?

Tags: org-mode, todo

I want to modify emacs/org-mode to make percentages display evenly:

Default behavior:

```
+ [75%] List#0...
+ [76%] List#1...
+ [100%] List#2...
+ [86%] List#3...
+ [100%] List#4...
+ [4%] List#5...
```

Desired behavior:

```
+ [075%] List#0...
+ [076%] List#1...
+ [100%] List#2...
+ [086%] List#3...
+ [100%] List#4...
+ [004%] List#5...
```

In other words, when it comes to the actual number, it should always be 3 characters long.

---

I've tried editing `(format "[%d%%]"` to `(format "[%03d%%]"` in 3 different places:

- /home/myuser/.config/emacs/.local/straight/build-29.2/org/org.el
- /home/myuser/.config/emacs/.local/straight/repos/org/lisp/org.el
- /usr/share/emacs/29.2/lisp/org/org.el.gz

But that's `.el`, I need to compile it to `.elc` I believe, and I notice there are pairing .elc for two of the files:

- /home/myuser/.config/emacs/.local/straight/build-29.2/org/org.elc
- /usr/share/emacs/29.2/lisp/org/org.elc

So now it's just a question, which one is the right file and how to compile it for use with my emacs instance?

I'm on Arch btw, emacs-29.2-1.

Comment: Relevant (compile and load .el): https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/35923/how-do-you-recompile-an-el-source-file-and-make-it-active-in-my-current-session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `org.el`, l. 9903 (or thereabouts depending on your version):

```el
                (if is-percent
                (format "[%d%%]" (floor (* 100.0 cnt-done)
                            (max 1 cnt-all)))
```

Change the format to

```
                (format "[%03d%%]" ....
```

to pad the value on the left with 0; or

```
                (format "[%3d%%]" ....
```

to pad it with spaces.

Do `C-h f format` to see all the available formats.

EDIT: there are actually three places in the Org mode code that use the `"[%d%%]"` format string:

```
org-colview.el:1342:  (format "[%d%%]"
org.el:9903:                (format "[%d%%]" (floor (* 100.0 cnt-done)
org-list.el:2654:          (if percent (format "[%d%%]" (floor (* 100.0 checked)
```

so for consistency's sake you should probably change all three of them (or make it a variable that can be customized, and then use the variable in all three places).

In addition to the questions you had (and I presume resolved for your setup), you should realize that forking a project like this and keeping future updates from reverting your changes is  always a problem, but one that is out-of-scope for this site. Having access to the sources through a version-control system (e.g. `git`) helps, but is no panacea: it is never painless.

Comment: Thanks! Almost there, I've updated the question.